# Bootstrap Carousel not cycling after first click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Have just updated my carousel.js to 3.2.0 as the previous version active class was applying after the item had slid.

Here is my markup.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel__indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel__items">
                    <figure class="carousel__items__item active">
                        {{ "1000x250" | placeholder | image_tag:'Slide 1' }}
                        <figcaption class="carousel__items__item__caption">Slide 1</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="carousel__items__item">
                        {{ "1000x250" | placeholder | image_tag:'Slide 2' }}
                        <figcaption class="carousel__items__item__caption">Slide 2</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="carousel__items__item">
                        {{ "1000x250" | placeholder | image_tag:'Slide 3' }}
                        <figcaption class="carousel__items__item__caption">Slide 3</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel__control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel__control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
```

My jQuery

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.2.0
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element).on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel__indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      =
    this.sliding     =
    this.interval    =
    this.$active     =
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.2.0'

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.carousel__items__item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.carousel__items__item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos) }) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', $(this.$items[pos]))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.carousel__items__item.active')
    var $next     = next || $active[type]()
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var fallback  = type == 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'
    var that      = this

    if (!$next.length) {
      if (!this.options.wrap) return
      $next = this.$element.find('.carousel__items__item')[fallback]()
    }

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd($active.css('transition-duration').slice(0, -1) * 1000)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  $(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {
      $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  })

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

So basically what is happening now is that it works on the first slide interaction, either clicking the indicators or controls, but then it stops working.

Nothing shows up in the console either.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like you modified the code of the carousel component. This is always an bad idea. Instead i would try to adjust my markup to the component code. In that way you shouldn't get any problems when updating to a newer version.

Comment: I don't want to modify the markup though, the markup is structured in a way that I prefer, and any of the code I have modified, like classes have been updated in the js.